# Javascript Array not outputs list which does not in another array list

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could you please help me to get below output on Javascript.

```
 var deselect = ["10001","10005"];
  
 var select = [{"UserId":"10000","ProfileName":"Finance"},{"UserId":"10001","ProfileName":"Admin"},{"UserId":"10002","ProfileName":"Admin"},{"UserId":"10003","ProfileName":"Standard User"}];
```

I tried using below code, but could not able to get below mentioned output.

```
 var output= deselect.filter(item => !select.includes(item.UserId));
```

Output should be - 10005

Comment: `var output = deselect.filter(UserId => !select.some(item => item.UserId === UserId));`

Comment: I removed all the tags that had nothing to do with the question you asked.

Comment: My solution offers two different ways of achieving this. Would you prefer the final output to be an array of any values not found, a (comma-)delimited string, or just the first non-found value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually very close. `includes()` would only work if your `select` array was a simple array of values instead of an array of objects. Instead, use a negation of the `some()` method to check if any of the objects in your `select` array contain a `UserId` matching the items in question.

Here it is:

```js
var deselect = ["10001","10005"];
var select = [{"UserId":"10000","ProfileName":"Finance"},{"UserId":"10001","ProfileName":"Admin"},{"UserId":"10002","ProfileName":"Admin"},{"UserId":"10003","ProfileName":"Standard User"}];

var output = deselect.filter(item => !select.some(obj => obj.UserId === item));

console.log(output);
```

Another method would be to map the `select` array of objects as a simple array of the `UserId` values and then perform your original `includes()` logic:

```js
var deselect = ["10001","10005"];
var select = [{"UserId":"10000","ProfileName":"Finance"},{"UserId":"10001","ProfileName":"Admin"},{"UserId":"10002","ProfileName":"Admin"},{"UserId":"10003","ProfileName":"Standard User"}];

var output = deselect.filter(item => !select.map(obj => obj.UserId).includes(item));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you @brandon

Comment: You're welcome @lochana glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Extract the IDs that you want to ignore first then `filter` using them.

```js
const
  deselect = [ "10001", "10005" ],
  select = [
    { "UserId": "10000" , "ProfileName": "Finance"       },
    { "UserId": "10001" , "ProfileName": "Admin"         },
    { "UserId": "10002" , "ProfileName": "Admin"         },
    { "UserId": "10003" , "ProfileName": "Standard User" }
  ];

const
  ignoreIds = select.map(({ UserId }) => UserId),
  output = deselect.filter(userId => !ignoreIds.includes(userId));

console.log(output);
```

If you want to find only the first, use `find`.

```js
const
  deselect = [ "10001", "10005" ],
  select = [
    { "UserId": "10000" , "ProfileName": "Finance"       },
    { "UserId": "10001" , "ProfileName": "Admin"         },
    { "UserId": "10002" , "ProfileName": "Admin"         },
    { "UserId": "10003" , "ProfileName": "Standard User" }
  ];

const
  ignoreIds = select.map(({ UserId }) => UserId),
  output = deselect.find(userId => !ignoreIds.includes(userId));

console.log(output);
```

You could take this one step further by creating a reusable thunk as a filter to cache the IDs.

```js
const
  deselect = [ "10001", "10005", "10007" ],
  select = [
    { "UserId": "10000" , "ProfileName": "Finance"       },
    { "UserId": "10001" , "ProfileName": "Admin"         },
    { "UserId": "10002" , "ProfileName": "Admin"         },
    { "UserId": "10003" , "ProfileName": "Standard User" }
  ];

const Filter = (selectOptions, extractorFn) => (ids => ({
  findAll: (values, invert = false) =>  
    values.filter(id => ids.includes(id) === !invert),
  findOne: (values, invert = false) =>
    values.find(id => ids.includes(id) === !invert),
}))
(typeof extractorFn === 'function'
  ? selectOptions.map(extractorFn) : selectOptions);

const filter = Filter(select, ({ UserId }) => UserId);

console.log(filter.findOne(deselect, true));
console.log(filter.findAll(deselect, true));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you Polywhirl

Answer (score 1):

```js
var deselect = ["10001", "10005"];
        
        var select = [{ "UserId": "10000", "ProfileName": "Finance" }, { "UserId": "10001", "ProfileName": "Admin" }, { "UserId": "10002", "ProfileName": "Admin" }, { "UserId": "10003", "ProfileName": "Standard User" }];
        var output = deselect.filter(item => !(select.filter(it => it.UserId == item).length > 0))
        
        console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Thank you @Cesars